# Perlin noise not generating number between 1 and -1

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm developing a game in Java using **LibGDX** and I wanted random terrain generation. I found a **Perlin** class online and decided to use it for my project.

I currently have a simple world class with this as constructor:

```
public World() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    seed = rand.nextInt();
    Perlin perlin = new Perlin(seed);

    for(int x = 0; x < map.length; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < map.length; y++) {
            map[x][y] = perlin.noise2(x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

(map is a 2d float array ofcourse)

In my game's **main** class I create a world and then draw it in the `render()` method like this:

```
batch.begin();
for (int x = 0; x < w.getMap().length; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < w.getMap().length; y++) {
        if (w.getMap()[x][y] <= 0) {
            batch.draw(water, x * 32, y * 32);
        }
        if (w.getMap()[x][y] > 0) {
            batch.draw(grass, x * 32, y * 32);
        } else {
            log.severe("not between -1 and 1");             
        }
    }
}
batch.end();
```

Upon execution it basically spams the console with "not between -1 and 1" and after some time the screen fills up with water texture.

Is it the class or am I messing up? Probably the latter. How should I fix it? Also, any tips on optimizing? Code kinda looks messy right now.

[This is the class I'm using. Posted it on pastebin because it's ~580 lines long.](http://pastebin.com/HBY7ALaC)

**UPDATE:** I fixed the log spam, which was kind of a stupid mistake that Rogue pointed out.

Now I'm facing a different problem. It seems to only be generating water. I checked what `getMap()[x][y]` was returning and it was basically only 0.0s and -0.0s.

Comment: Do you not want that 2nd "if" to be an "else"?  This would get rid of the need for your other else and spammy log since that situation would then be impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think the obvious one is that your else-if logic is off, you're using two `if` statements in a row:

```
    if (w.getMap()[x][y] <= 0) {
        batch.draw(water, x * 32, y * 32);
    }
    if (w.getMap()[x][y] > 0) {
        batch.draw(grass, x * 32, y * 32);
    } else {
        log.severe("not between -1 and 1");             }
    }
```

The bracket alignment is also a bit iffy, but try using `if` `else if` `else`:

```
    if (w.getMap()[x][y] <= 0) {
        batch.draw(water, x * 32, y * 32);
    } else if (w.getMap()[x][y] > 0) {
        batch.draw(grass, x * 32, y * 32);
    } else {
        log.severe("not between -1 and 1");
    }
```

Previously anything below 0 would've printed that error.

Comment: That seems to be the problem! Haha, I should refresh on the basics and I'm crazy tired right now. Thanks! Still weird how it drew the water texture after a while.